# Can I pass a Javascript object out to an Android WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am migrating a web application into an android version.
After having received and processed JSON data, I have an array of Javascript objects being held within the page.

How can I pass the complete contents of one of the javascript objects "out" to the webview container for display using native android controls ?

Eventually, I could create a javascript interface with a method having parameters for each of the possible javascript object properties - but this appears to be overly heavy.

Can anyone help with this ?

Comment: Check answers in similar thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250917/passing-a-javascript-object-using-addjavascriptinterface-on-android/32698399#32698399

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Android's `WebView` contains a method called `addJavascriptInterface(Object obj, String interfaceName)` that should be useful here.

Using this method, the object `obj` that you add as the interface can be accessed via JavaScript code in the Web View. In your case, you could pass in an object that has a setter method that transfers some JavaScript object back to Java.

You'll still need to create the glue code that converts your JavaScript object into the JSON object. For a quick approach, you can just have your interface generate a JSONObject on the Java side using a JSON string passed from JavaScript. The `JSONObject` class in Java has a constructor that accepts a String containing JSON data. So, you can pass the stringified result directly back to Java and create the object that way. For example:

```
class JSInterface {
    HashMap<String, JSONObject> mObjectsFromJS = new HashMap<String, JSONObject>();
    public void passObject(String name, String json) {
        mObjectsFromJS.put(name, new JSONObject(json));
    }
}

//At some point, register using:
mJSInterface = new JSInterface();
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(mJSInterface, "Android");
```

Then, on the JavaScript side, in the handler that has a blob of unparsed JSON in the variable jsonData:

```
Android.passObject("pageItems", jsonData);
```

Now, your JSInterface on the Java side will have a JSONObject containing the items, which you can access using the getters provided by JSONObject. The objects created via the Javascript call will be in the `mObjectsFromJS` map. You'll of course want to add additional helper methods to the JSInterface class to allow for managing the objects better.

I haven't compiled or tested any of these methods, so you may have to tweak them a bit for proper operation. But hopefully this gives you the idea.

However, if the objects have a consistent interface and data items, it would be more sensible to just create a simple JavaScript glue function that binds the JavaScript object properties to the Java-side object fields using setter methods.

**PLEASE NOTE** 
This is giving remote code ability to trigger native code on your device. If you do not have complete control over the pages/scripts being loaded into the `WebView`, you should ensure that the behavior exposed by `obj` doesn't allow any exploits.

Comment: Thank you Jason,

From what you are saying, it is not possible to "simply" pass javascript object directly to a java setter function and expect it to be translated.

So, to resume, I would need to : 

- take my JSON object and revert it back to a json encoded string

- pass the encoded string back up through the javascript interface

- decode it into a java object

All that to be able to access the data correctly.

Thank you for clarifying this.

Comment: After having tried to get this answer to work, I have found out that the javascript interface is completely broken in v2.3.x of Android. Shame.

Comment: what if I want to make my Java function a constructor, so I would call e.g. `var ob = new Android.MyObject()`, how would I return a native javascript object?