# Is it possible for WebView to read javascript object from React?

Tags: android, android-webview

Suppose that I have this in my React

```
render() {
    let anImage= (
        <img src="image.jpg" alt="image">
    ); 
}
```

If I opened a page containing that in WebView, how can I get the value of `anImage`? By value, I mean a mere string contains `<img src="image.jpg" alt="image">`. Is it possible?

I knew about `JavascriptInterface` for WebView, but tbh, so far it doesn't give me the result I hope. I've tried one from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979398/can-i-pass-a-javascript-object-out-to-an-android-webview), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991515/android-extract-javascript-variable-from-webview-using-javascript-interface). And then I realized, the page I tried to read from is from React. Thus I wonder if there's a particular way for that?

Comment: cant contact you due stackoverflow but i wrote a solution for your problem (focus edittext when clicking other elements. Just ask it again and i post the solution)

Comment: @EmanuelSeibold here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43449086/how-to-make-edittexts-parent-clickable