# How to pass a Blob object from javascript to Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, blob

I have a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) object inside my WebView, how can I pass it to Android?
I want to save it to local file on device.

I been trying to use:

```
var url = webkitURL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
```

But I wasn't been able to download it to device.

Comment: Could you please add some of your code?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250917/passing-a-javascript-object-using-addjavascriptinterface-on-android

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution by converting the blob to Base64 String

```
 var reader = new window.FileReader();
 reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
 reader.onloadend = function() {
                var base64data = reader.result;                
                // send base64data string to android as a method param
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but then how does Android java turn that base64 encoded string back into binary?

Comment: @DavidFaux Use `android.util.Base64`, and take a look on what you are getting from the WebView, I don't remember if it been prefixed with mime type. But as for the decoding, `android.util.Base64` should do the work.

Comment: Thanks, this works nicely for small blobs like under 10mb. I think the hex64 encoding crashes Chromium for larger blobs like size 50mb.

Comment: @DavidFaux Than you can split it for packages under 10MB and processes those.

Answer (score 7):

I haven't tried this, but i was able to found some information pointing to the usage of Javascript Interfaces with WebViews. Basically you can assign Java Classes to work like Javascript classes in your WebView (and exchange information between both sides).
I'm not a pro at JavaScript object types, so i'll leave that to you.

First, create a `JavaScriptHandler` class with a reference to your activity that controls the `WebView`:

```
public class JavaScriptHandler {
    MyActivity parentActivity;

    public JavaScriptHandler(MyActivity activity) {
        parentActivity = activity;
    }

    public void doSomething(<Your blob format> data){    
        // .............
        // ..Some code..
        // .............
    }
}
```

After that you'll be adding your `JavaScriptHandler` to your `WebView` in your main `Activity`. Don't forget to enable JavaScript in your `WebView`!

```
myWebView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptHandler(this), "MyHandler");
```

The first parameter passed to addJavaScriptInterface() is the JavaScript interface object itself. The second parameter is the name of the global JavaScript variable which the JavaScript interface object is bound to.

Now all you gotta do is call your `Java` method with `JavaScript`.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sendBlob() {
            MyHandler.doSomething(<Your Blob>);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="sendBlob()" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple file downloader using JavaScript.

Here is a sample to download blob as file.

```js
var saveData = (function() {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.style = "display: none";
  return function(data, fileName) {
    var json = JSON.stringify(data),
      blob = new Blob([json], {
        type: "octet/stream"
      }),
      url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  };
}());

var data = {
    x: 42,
    s: "hello, world",
    d: new Date()
  },
  fileName = "my-download.json";

saveData(data, fileName);
```

Comment: This will alert the user if he want's to save the file, and it will save it in a public storage.

Comment: Yes, If you want to save file, you can use file api of html5, Here is http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/