# element.childElementCount is return incorrect value

Tags: javascript, android-webview

I want to select element have no child.

This is js code

```js
var elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");

elements.each(function(element) {
  if (element.childElementCount == 0) {
    element.addEventListener(
      "click",
      function() {
        makeBorder(selectedElement, false);
        selectedElement = element;
        makeBorder(element, true);
      },
      false
    );
  } else {
    element.removeEventListener("click", null, false);
    element.removeEventListener("onclick", null, false);
  }
});
```

From link "m.naver.com", class["grid1 id_cui_cupid_news _MM_AIRS_CONTAINER"]'s real childElementCount is not 0.

But in code, childElementCount is 0.

I'm running this code in android webview.

How can I get the element that has no child?

reference : [Select element inside WebView and get details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299667/select-element-inside-webview-and-get-details?rq=1)

[[[[[[[ Edited ]]]]]]

```js
Object.prototype.each = function(fn, bind) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (i in this) {
            fn.call(bind, this[i], i, this);
        }
    }
};

var selectedElement = null;

document.getElementsByTagName("*").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
 if(e.target && e.target.childElementCount == 0) {
  
  makeBorder(selectedElement, false);
  selectedElement = element;
  makeBorder(element, true);
 }
});

// here

var makeBorder = function(element, selected) {
    if (element) {
        element.style.cssText = selected ? 'background: #CDEA90;' : '';
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you missing a library (or maybe mispelt `forEach`) as your example doesn't work.

Comment: @evolutionxbox oh...reference link is incorrect. I have changed the link. there is no library. only javascript.

Comment: `elements.each` will still throw an error.

Comment: @evolutionxbox but i can get element in function of addEventListener(). sometimes element.childElementCount is 0. but it have children.

Comment: No I mean it `elements.each is not a function`

Comment: Convert elements to an array and then filter said array by `element.children.length`

Comment: @evolutionxbox thank you, i will test your advice tomorrow. now i'm in home :D

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry, I'm late...I changed the code like this. `var list = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.body.getElementsByTagName('*'));   list.forEach(function(element) {...}`. but result is same.

Comment: Why don't you use a delegate event? https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate. E.g. listen to the body and only do things when you match an element you want.

Comment: @evolutionxbox then, is this code right? `document.getElementsByTagName("*").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
 if(e.target && e.target.childElementCount == 0) { //TODO } });`

Comment: I have added a modified JavaScript to the article.

Comment: Maybe target `document.body` instead of `getElementsByTagName(‘*’)`

Comment: @evolutionxbox I suddenly thought. If it is an element added by communicating with ajax, it seems that it can not be pressed. I'm runnig this code in Android webview. If I want to use custom js, I should load js after onPageFinished().