# Passing Javascript object throught JavascriptInterface to Android application

Tags: javascript, java

I have to pass one Javascript object using JavascriptInterface.
I've already lots of function which implements JavascriptInterface but I only pass String objects and I've never tried to pass a not-primitive one.

In my .jsp:

```
var trnsCfg = {}

trnsCfg['trn_enb'] = '1';

trnsCfg['lang'] = 'it_IT';

window.JSInterface.startTranslator(trnsCfg);
```

In my .java:

```
@JavascriptInterface

public void startTranslator(ObjectIWantToUse object){

    object.doSomethingWithIt();

    //something

};
```

In this example used `ObjectIWantToUse` but what I have pratically put? And how will I be able to use this Object properties (like `'trn_enb'` or `'lang'`)?

Comment: You want to code a function in Javascript and then execute it in Java??  Or do you just want to access the object properties?

Comment: I want to access the object properties like a simple data structure

Comment: Try this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250917/passing-a-javascript-object-using-addjavascriptinterface-on-android/32698399#32698399

Comment: Ok, I'll try thank you