# How to find object in Array that produce an error with JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, android, json, parsing

I'm doing an app with a part native and a part with html. I need to send the phone contacts to the html part, which later parse the JSON passed to a json object in Javascript with JSON.parse. Sometimes, it fails and I don't have anyway to know in which contact is failing.

Some advice to know the error? In Android or in javacript, thank you.

JS parse

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  (<any>window).contactsOk = function (contacts) {
    try {
      const data = JSON.parse(contacts);
      resolve(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error parsing contacts info', error);
      reject(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: parse it in native.. much better. It will let you know where the error is occurring

Comment: What kind of error? How are you constructing your JSONs?

Comment: It shows an error occurring while parsing, but I don't know where. This is why I'm asking this question. :(

Answer (score 1):

Please check this post 
[Passing a JavaScript object using addJavascriptInterface() on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250917/passing-a-javascript-object-using-addjavascriptinterface-on-android)

You can pass as primitive and String. Avoid passing JSON object to JavaScript
Convert Json object to String and then send