# Send Object from Javascript to Kotlin using Webview

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, android-webview, javascript-injection

I have loaded a webpage using WebView component and added a JavascriptInterface. Please check the code below,

```
val webview = WebView(this)
setContentView(webview)
webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webview.loadUrl(HOME_PAGE_URL)
webview.addJavascriptInterface(JavascriptInterface(),”javascript_bridge”)
```

And when I call the invoke from Javascript using `window.javascript_bridge.showToast(“Information Saved”);`

```
private inner class JavascriptInterface
{
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    fun showToast(text: String?)
    {
        Log.d("WEBVIEW", text);
    }
}
```

I am able to call the method from Javascript to Kotlin without any trouble.

But now I want to pass an Object from Javascript to Kotlin like below,

```
var info = {
    message: “Information Saved”,
    ID: 123456
}
```

And when I call the invoke from Javascript using `window.javascript_bridge.showToast(info);`

I tried to change to the data type to Any, but the value passed from Javascript is null

```
private inner class JavascriptInterface
{
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    fun showToast(text: Any?)
    {
       Log.d("WEBVIEW", text.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know, the javaScript interface methods only accepts primitive types of data as parameters (as discussed on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250917/passing-a-javascript-object-using-addjavascriptinterface-on-android)).
If you still want to achieve that, you may serialize the object (to JSON format, for instance) in the javaScript and then Deserialize it in Java.
Hope it helps :)